# Transfer TFS Workitem Description as formatted text to word

Tags: c#, html, .net, vb.net, tfs

Has anybody any idea how to import a TFS Workitem to Word in .NET?

I'm trying to import a Workitem over the API but the description is passed to me as html-string.
Is there any possibility how to access a formatted String of the description or to convert the html-string into a formatted string?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called **Team Foundation Server Word Add-in**.

> The Team Foundation Server Word Add-in **imports work items** from a
>   Team Project and **generates professional-looking documents.** A
>   typical scenario is requirements management in Word Doc format,
>   allowing users to collaborate with the project team while using their
>   favorite application.
>
> *Note:* users will need to be appropriately licensed for Team Foundation Server access when using this tool.
>
> Source Link: [Team Foundation Server Word Add-in](https://vsarword4tfs.codeplex.com/)